# Invalid Pipe Datatodisplay

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I use angular CLI, firebase and angularfire2. I want to display particular data by selecting the firebase key but the console indicates that the pipe is invalid. Can someone help me please?

The value of this.patientid is the firebase key ...

// HTML

```
{{(patientToDisplay | async)?.nom}}
```

//Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Patient } from '../../models/patient.model';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PatientsService } from '../../services/patients.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
selector: 'app-single-patient',
templateUrl: './single-patient.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./single-patient.component.scss'],
providers: [PatientsService]
})

export class SinglePatientComponent implements OnInit {


patientId: string;
patientToDisplay;

constructor( 
private route: ActivatedRoute, 
private location: Location,
private patientsService: PatientsService,
private diagnosticsService: DiagnosticsService,
private router: Router, 
public dialog: MatDialog, 
private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
this.patientId = urlParameters['id'];
});
this.patientToDisplay = 
this.patientsService.getSinglePatient(this.patientId);
console.log(this.patientId);

}

}
```

//Service

```
getSinglePatient(Patientid: string){
return this.database.object('patients/' + Patientid);
}
```

Comment: @DiegoVenâncio Type 'AngularFireObject<{}>' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: patientToDisplay: Observable<any>; you should also type this and your get req but this is a formality after you get it working :)

Comment: the reason you are getting an invalid pipe error is because you never establish patientToDisplay as an observable. the async pipe expects an observable to pipe to

Comment: i have an error when i try console.log(this.database.object('patients/', Patientid););

Comment: i dont really use firebase so i can't help you there, but this seems un-related to your original question.

Comment: i tried  patientToDisplay: AngularFireObject<{}>;  but i have the same error

Comment: please see my answer below...this is the correct way. to use the async pipe, your member patientToDisplay needs to be typed to Observable<some type, or any>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return observable from your service, use this:

```
getSinglePatient(Patientid: string){
  return this.database.object('patients/' + Patientid).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: this makes sense. i am not up to speed on Firebase so my answer below may not be 100%

Comment: Yes Thank you Sandra Xillford and thant you Saksham Gupta it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`patientToDisplay: Observable<any>;`

you should also type this and your get req but this is a formality after you get it working :)

the reason you are getting an invalid pipe error is because you never establish patientToDisplay as an observable. the async pipe expects an observable to pipe to

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Patient } from '../../models/patient.model';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PatientsService } from '../../services/patients.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

@Component({
selector: 'app-single-patient',
templateUrl: './single-patient.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./single-patient.component.scss'],
providers: [PatientsService]
})

export class SinglePatientComponent implements OnInit {


patientId: string;
patientToDisplay: Observable<any>;

constructor( 
private route: ActivatedRoute, 
private location: Location,
private patientsService: PatientsService,
private diagnosticsService: DiagnosticsService,
private router: Router, 
public dialog: MatDialog, 
private formBuilder: FormBuilder
) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.forEach((urlParameters) => {
this.patientId = urlParameters['id'];
});
this.patientToDisplay = 
this.patientsService.getSinglePatient(this.patientId);
console.log(this.patientId);

}

}
```

Comment: @Sanndra Willford Thanks Sandra but angular don't like that :ERROR in src/app/patient-list/single-patient/single-patient.component.ts(38,4): error TS2322: Type 'AngularFireObject<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'AngularFireObject<{}>'.

Comment: try `Observable<AngularFireObject<{}>>`

Comment: Maybe there are a solution easier ?

Comment: you would need to put up a stackblitz or plunker at this point to really get any where further, I'm out of options without being able to work with it directly.